# Express res.json() losing data

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to send data using express but for some reason it losing part of data.

```
function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err);

  console.log(data);
  res.json(data);
}
```

Variable data looks like (simplified):

`{field1: 'value1', field2: 'value2', field3: {subfield: 'subvalue'}}`

But in the browser I receive:

`{field1: 'value1', field2: 'value2', field3: null }`

Am I doing something wrong or missing something?

Update:

Full code

```
UserReadingData.find({
    UserId: {
        "$exists": true,
        "$eq": user._id
    },
    InFuture: false,
    Stopped: false
})
.populate('SeriesId', 'SeriesName')
.exec(function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log(data);
    res.json(data);
});
```

And SeriesId in browser is null.

Update 2:

Result of console.log(data):

```
{ Issues: 
 [ 575efe1c3d6d04662a2cd1c4
   575efe1c3d6d04662a2cd1d3 ],
Stopped: false,
InFuture: false,
__v: 0,
SeriesId: 
 { SeriesName: 'Test name',
   _id: 575efe1b3d6d04662a2cd188 },
UserId: 561c080aa849427a8699cafd,
_id: 575f0981ddac1c802d9d1536 }
```

Update 3:

My schemas

```
var seriesSchema = mongoose.Schema({
Meta: metaInformationSchema,
SeriesName: String,
Description: String,
Creators: [creatorsSchema],
Featured: [featuredSchema],
PublisherName: String,
IsStoryArc: Boolean,
Issues: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Issue'
}]}, {
collection: 'library'});

var userReadingDataSchema = mongoose.Schema({
UserId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
},
SeriesId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Series'
},
Issues: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Issue'
}],
InFuture: Boolean,
Stopped: Boolean}, {collection: 'readingdata'});
```

I came from sql and it's first time when i used mongo.

Comment: What exactly is `data`? Where is it coming from?

Comment: I updated a question with full code

Comment: Does `user.id` actually exist in the DB?

Comment: "*And SeriesId in browser is null.*" Is `SeriesName` also null?

Comment: `user.id` exists and `SeriesName` is not null. I checked in console before send that data filled with correct values.

Comment: Can you post your schema?

Comment: I updates a question with schemas of `Series` and `UserReadingData`. Also updated output of console because before posted old one.

Comment: Have you tried stringifying the data and parsing it on the other end?
JSON.stringify(data), JSON.parse(data)

Comment: Yes, `SeriesId` still null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know real reason what was wrong, but i removed everything from collection `readingdata` and filled it with some new data. After it `res.json` worked correctly.